# How to pass long value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have javascript function:

```
function someAction(thisTd,text){
  alert(text);
  thisTd.innerHTML=text;
  ...
}
```

And html-file:

```
<td onclick="someAction(this,<?echo 'Long-long text with <b>html-formatting</b>'?>)"/>
```

When I use such code function someAction doesn't call (because alert doesn't show) and in the error console in Opera no error is displayed. How to fix this problem?
P.S. I do not use frameworks(JQuery etc.).
**UPDATE #1**
When I use such code:

```
<?$encoded=str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\r\n","",$text));echo $encoded?>
```

It works nice. But I'm not sure, that it work correct in Linux.(I use Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you [HTML encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) it and put single quotes around the parameter:

```
<td onclick="someAction(this, '<?echo htmlspecialchars('Long-long text with <b>html-formatting</b>', ENT_QUOTES) ?>')"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remoce echo tag and the ?

```
 <div onclick="someAction(this,'Long-long text with <b>html-formatting</b>')">myDiv</div>
```

and your function is :

```
function someAction(thisTd,text){
    thisTd.nodeValue=innerHTML
    ...
}
```

Comment: Text is sample. In fact, there should be variable.

Comment: you can do someAction(thisTd,someVariable) and in the javascript call your php script

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap the string in single or html encoded double quotes in the first place:

```
<td onclick="someAction(this, '<?php echo 'yada yada'; ?>');"/>
<!-- OR -->
<td onclick="someAction(this, &quot;<?php echo 'yada yada'; ?>&quot;);"/>
```

Secondly, the "echo"ed output can contain single or double quotes that can break the javascript string or the html attribute. Assuming that you're using single quotes to wrap the echoed string:

```
<td onclick="someAction(this, '<?php echo htmlspecialchars( str_replace( "'", "\\'", $that_long_text ) ); ?>');"/>
```

Comment: I use such code:  <td onclick="someAction(this, &quot;<?echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace( "'", "\\'", $text ), ENT_QUOTES)?/>  but it's not work.

Comment: I don't see a `?>` in the comment but may be its a typo. But I also do not see the closing `&quot;`. Also, If you're using `"` (correctly encoded as `&quot;`) as the string delimiter then you should replace all `"` with `\"`; not `'` with `\'`.

Comment: Yes, it's typo.  When I use this: onclick="someAction(this, &quot;<?echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace( '"', '\"',$text), ENT_QUOTES);?>&quot;)"  it's give such code: onclick="someAction(this, " <p>sdf</p> <p><strong>sdfsdf</strong></p> ")"

Comment: Assuming that what you pasted was copied from the "view-source" of the generated page, I see that you have double quotes inside the onclick attribute. Encode them or use single quote: `onclick="someAction(this, ' <p>sdf</p> <p><strong>sdfsdf</strong></p> ')"`

Answer (score 0):

Just put the quotes around the text, you're producing:

Logically, this gives an error.

Use simple quotes or escape double quotes (\")